# How often can a Google form receive responses?

Tags: google-forms

I am designing a test using Google Form. It has a time limit, after which the form will not accept responses. I am concerning that at the very last second, there will be 20 responses submit and Google Form might have a problem collecting all of those. Is there a document anywhere state the capability of Google Form accepting responses?
The capability is something like data size over time or amount of responses in a period of time, not maximum storage ability or Google Sheet linkage.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what are you asking as well to include a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has no published a any limit regarding the number of responses that can be received by a Google Form but there are reports of people getting problems with form response submissions some of the most common problems are related to forms sending responses to a spreadsheet and/or using on form submit triggers.

Comment: I guess sometimes the answer is there is no answer. I struggled a bit with the setup of submit trigger as well.